# SQL name error with foreign key in sql code

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting ORA-00955 error which is name is already used by an existing object. I know it is in the foreign key constraint im trying to use. It happens in both foreign key constraints. I cant figure out why its happening. I tried renaming them to anything possible and I cant understand why it wont work.

```
DROP TABLE STUDENT;
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(stuID VARCHAR (7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
major VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
yr  VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE ENROLL;
CREATE TABLE ENROLL
(stuID VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
grade VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL,
courseID VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_STUDENT
   FOREIGN KEY (stuID)
   REFERENCES STUDENT(stuid)
);

DROP TABLE CLASS;
CREATE TABLE CLASS
(instructorID VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
classRoomNumber VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
dateStarts DATE NOT NULL,
courseID VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fk_INSTRUCTOR
  FOREIGN KEY (instructorID)
  REFERENCES INSTRUCTOR(instructorid)
);

DROP TABLE INSTRUCTOR;
CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR
(firstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
departmentName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
instructorID VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You cannot define a reference to a table that does not exist yet. Put `instructor` above `class`

Comment: I did that and im still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you said that there's still an error.

If you create (and/or drop) tables in a correct order, everything is OK. I prefer dropping them separately.

At first, tables don't exist so I'll just create them:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student (
  2    stuid       VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3    major       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  4    firstname   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  5    lastname    VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  6    yr          VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE enroll (
  2    stuid      VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  3    grade      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  4    courseid   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  5    CONSTRAINT fk_student FOREIGN KEY ( stuid )
  6      REFERENCES student ( stuid )
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE instructor (
  2    firstname        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  3    lastname         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  4    departmentname   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  5    instructorid     VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE class (
  2    instructorid      VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  3    classroomnumber   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  4    datestarts        DATE NOT NULL,
  5    courseid          VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  6    description       CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  7    CONSTRAINT fk_instructor FOREIGN KEY ( instructorid )
  8      REFERENCES instructor ( instructorid )
  9  );

Table created.
```

Drop tables in reverse order, so that detail is dropped before its master

```
SQL> DROP TABLE enroll;

Table dropped.

SQL> DROP TABLE student;

Table dropped.

SQL> DROP TABLE class;

Table dropped.

SQL> DROP TABLE instructor;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Table `INSTRUCTOR` is referenced by table `CLASS`, hence you heed to create table `INSTRUCTOR` **before** you create table `CLASS`.

Also, you should use `DROP TABLE ... CASCADE CONSTRAINTS` instead of just `DROP TABLE ...`. This allows foreign and primary keys to be properly dropped at the same time as the table, and might avoid error `name already used by existing object` that you are currently getting.